# SelectQuery eating up 100% CPU

Tags: c#, windows, wmi

I am doing a query for all the users on the machine and when it executes it grabs 100% CPU and locks up the system. I have waited up to 5 minutes and nothing happens.

In the Task Manager wmiprvse.exe is using all the CPU. When I kill that process everything returns to normal.

Here is my code:

```
        SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount", 
            "LocalAccount=1 and Domain='" + GetMachine().DomainName + "'");
        using(ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query)) {
            IList<WindowsUser> users = new List<WindowsUser>();
            Console.WriteLine("Getting users...");
            foreach (ManagementObject envVar in searcher.Get()) {
                Console.WriteLine("Getting " + envVar["Name"].ToString() + "...");
            }
        }
```

In the console all I see is Getting users... and nothing else. The problem appears to be with searcher.Get().

Does anyone know why this query is taking 100% CPU? Thanks.

**EDIT:** OK I found that it the WMI process is only eating 25% CPU but it doesn't get released if I end the program (the query never finishes). The next time I start an instance the process goes up to 50% CPU, etc, etc until it is at 100%.

So my new question is why is the CPU not getting released and how long should a query like this take to complete?

Comment: Usually, if the query is taking a very long time to return, or not returning at all, it is because of an improper join condition.  I am not very good with .NET so I am not sure what your actually query in SQL would look like.

Comment: Ahh, I removed my conditions and the query executed so that must be it. If you post this as an answer I can give you the credit. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it didn't seem like much of an answer, so I made it a comment.  I'm not really worried about reputation point, just trying to help, but thank you.

Comment: Turns out the Domain being return from my GetMachine method was like server.domain.com but I guess windows wanted soemthing like SERVER. Turns out this was just a dumb question but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount",  "LocalAccount=1 and Domain='" + GetMachine().DomainName + "'"); 
using(ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query)) { 
  IList<WindowsUser> users = new List<WindowsUser>(); 
  Console.WriteLine("Getting users...");
  ManagementObjectCollection myCollection = searcher.Get();
  foreach (ManagementObject envVar in MyCollection){ 
    Console.WriteLine("Getting " + envVar["Name"].ToString() + "..."); 
  } 
}
```